# RequireJS : Missing file gives error for first time but results in request timeout for further requests until server is restarted

Tags: node.js, requirejs, npm

I'm using RequireJS for loading modules but if one unavailable file is required, it gives error for first request but skips errors for successive requests and result in request timeout.

A sample of code I'm using :

```
var requireJS = require("requirejs");
var Q = require("q");
var fxndef = "some-test-function-definition";


function test1(){
var d = Q.defer();

 requireJS([fxndef.source], function (requireModule) {
    if (!requireModule) {
    d.reject(new Error("Function not found for[" + JSON.stringify(fxndef) + "]"));
    return;
    }
    var loadedFunction = requireModule[fxndef.name];
    if (loadedFunction) {
    d.resolve(loadedFunction);
    } else {
    d.reject(new Error("Function not found for[" + JSON.stringify(fxndef.name) + "]"));
    }
 });
 requireJS.onError = function (err) {

    console.log("In Error......")
    d.reject(err);
 };
}

test1();
test1();
```

The above code snippet receives a error for one time only and not twice as expected.

What am i missing ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on requirejs, but this may not be a requirejs issue.  I think you are missing the second error because your code is completing before the asynchronous operation is done for the second method call.  Try running this slightly modified code (note that we are returning d.promise, and handing the results to console.log):

```
var requireJS = require("requirejs");
var Q = require("q");
var fxndef = "some-test-function-definition";


function test1(){
var d = Q.defer();

requireJS([fxndef.source], function (requireModule) {
    if (!requireModule) {
    d.reject(new Error("Function not found for[" + JSON.stringify(fxndef) + "]"));
    return;
    }   
    var loadedFunction = requireModule[fxndef.name];
    if (loadedFunction) {
    d.resolve(loadedFunction);
    } else {
    d.reject(new Error("Function not found for[" + JSON.stringify(fxndef.name) + "]"));
    }   
 }); 

 requireJS.onError = function (err) {
    console.log("In Error......")
    d.reject(err);
 };

 return d.promise;
}

test1().done(console.log, console.log)
test1().done(console.log, console.log)
```